# Prestashop Technical Error: Details: Error Thrown: [Object Object] Text Status: Parsererror

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am getting this error when trying to add weight ranges to shipping carriers that I have. It mostly seems to happen at random and I have been able to complete some of the carriers but others will cause the error every  time.  The console reports the following: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Is there a solution for this?  I couldn't find anything online about it.

I have v. 1.6.1.4

Thank you!

Comment: enable error debugging on your store and see if there is any error appearing in your console....

Answer (score 1):

You have to use firefox developper and when you get the "Parseerror"
using the developper tools you go to network and select your last query.
On the right you have a window with all the options of the query : cookies parameters... select response.
You should see the response of the parse error.

For me it was just a parameter of the form that could not be empty.
Putting a random word made everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when adding weight ranges.

The annoying thing is i had to restore a backup of the tables ps_range_weight and ps_carrier.. as for every single instance of 
"Prestashop Technical Error: Details: Error Thrown: [Object Object] Text Status: Parsererror"  it made a new entry and i ended up with over 700 weight ranges.

Anyways, i restored to the last fucntioning versions of ps_range_weight and ps_carrier (needed doing) and disabled the standard paypal plugin from prestashop. After that it worked fine.
.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this on Prestashop 1.7
This happened to me as well when I changed the theme, however, I checked the Database and found that the carrier ID in ps_range_weight has randomly changed!

**Solution**
Fix the carrier ID in the database to the correct one and this error should not be appearing again! Good luck
[ps_range_weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0ham.png)